# How to align an UILabel to the right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alignment, uilabel, autolayout

I want to align an `UILabel` to the right. It called labeldistance. labeldistance appear if I autoresizing left (In this situation the label shown middle of the line). If I select right in autoresizing, labeldistance disappear. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: So you want to align text inside UILabel or you want to align UILabel in your view?

Comment: I want to align UILabel. I have UITable with 5 rows. All rows have 2 UILabel side by side. I want to align right the second UILabel.

Comment: So you have UITableView with custom cell with UILabel? or you are using label property of regular TableView.

Comment: I have UITableView with custom cell with UILabel.

Comment: Second label frame X value = firstlabel.frame.origin.x+firstlabel.frame.size.width +(Some margin)... it will add second label right to the first label with some margin

Comment: I suggest you to enable Autolayout on your custom cell view and put assign constraints according to your design. By the way i am also Turkish you may contact me from info on my profile if you need further assistance.

Comment: bpolat I sent e-mail with an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
labeldistance.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Comment: if you are using storyboard or XIB, you need to add some constraints

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `UIStoryboard` and select the `UILabel` you want to set the specific alignment.

If just aligning to the right, just use the arrow in the `Size Inspector` like this:[image]

For resizing the `UILabel` horizontal, add the middle arrow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this screen shot helps - you want to add a constraint for the right alignment of your view (in this case, a UILabel) but since you're now using constraints, you also have to define the height, width, and vertical position.

[image]